# How to enable right click on desktop? (Linux Mint 12 LXDE)

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, lxde

I accidentally disabled right clicking on the desktop in LXDE. Does anybody know how to enable it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the following command in the terminal:

> pcmanfm --desktop-pref

That gets the **Desktop Preferences** window opened. Click the advanced tab, and uncheck the **show menus...**